# Verify an XML Element using C#

Tags: c#, xml

How do we verify XML Elements in C#.Net

Xml sample:

```
<Employee>
<Name>Taha</Name>
<Age>25</Age>
</Employee>
```

If someone sent me the  above example but by mistake he forgot to add 'Age' Element, then how would I verify it in C#?

Comment: Taha i added sample very interessant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with XSD in order to validate your xml

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astfyhd4%28v=vs.100%29

You have sample very interessant in this link

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c6737/Validation-of-XML-with-XSD.htm

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to use [XML Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and verify against that.

You may see this article on Code project: [C# - XML Schema Validator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8781/C-XML-Schema-Validator)

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the other posted answers: You need to do some schema validation to what you want. However, you need a schema. If you don't have one, you need to create one.

You have two options:

1. Write one by hand
2. Use xsd.exe ([XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Option one is fairly straightforward, but tedious.
Option two is also fairly straightforward, and pretty quick. With xsd.exe you also have the option of generating C# classes which you can use to manipulate your documents in code and serialise to XML.